# Display rows in MVC .NET from joining tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new in MVC .ASP NET and LINQ.

Here is my question.

I have got a table that contains employees (ID, Name)

```
1  Foo
```

and a table that holds capacity about them (ID, EmployeeID, Hours, Date)

```
ID - EmployeeID - Hours - Date
1     1           100     January
2     1           50      February
```

writing a linq query to join all of them results in

[EmployeeID, Name, Hours, Date] records

But what i want to display is something like

```
Name - January -Feb - Mar ...
Foo     100
                 50
Foo2 ...
```

---

How can I do that?
Do I need to use a more sophisticated query to get the results in that way?
Or format them in the controller or in the view?

Comment: Is your question how to write the query or how to display it in the view?

Comment: @user3153169 i can write the join query but the data set returned isnt helpful to display the results in the format i want. So which is a better approach change the linq query or the view?

Comment: You should take a look at an ORM framework like Entity Framework, it makes your life much easier. Instead of juggling with tables you can comfortably work with objects.

Comment: Use an ORM, then you can use `strongly typed` views which easens displaying data a lot!

Comment: @Robert I have used the EF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Helper method that gets the number of the month by given string/date, then you could loop in your View like this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)</td>
        @for(var i = 0; i < numberOfWorkDays; i++)
        {
            <td>
                @if(YourHelper.GetNumberOfMonth(item.Date) == i)
                {
                    Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Hours)
                }
            <td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: i do have that. How do I view them in the format I want with looping the rows only once

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Check the updated answer